# How to auto obfuscate email addresses in rich text field

Tags: emails

I'm used to this feature in ExpressionEngine either natively or via the Auto Linker plugin, where you just wrap it around all the text fields. I've seen the [Sprout Encode Email](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/encode-email) addon but that doesn't search through text and apply it.
I don't mind if it doesn't create a mailto link, I just want to obfuscate every email address that appears in any of the text fields in a template.

Comment: What do you mean by "obfuscate", exactly? Can you give an example of how you want the email addresses to look?

Comment: I want it to convert any string of text that looks like an email address (xxx@xxx.xxx) within a text field into an encoded string to make it harder for robot harvesters. Look at the above link doc to see what the Sprout one does.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a really quick Plugin for you to use that uses the `_encodeStringRot13` function from the Sprout guys to use on any variable you want in Craft. What the Plugin does is to give you a new Twig filter that you can apply like this `{{ entry.body|protectEmails }}` and voila! - all `<a href="mailto:">` will be encoded in ROT13 (reference: http://snipplr.com/view/6037/) on output.

Download it here: http://www.naboovalley.com/craft/toolkit.rar

Comment: Thanks, but they won't be mailto links to start with. Content authors will just type/copy the email address into the text field, so the filter needs to look for any xxx@xxx.xxx string and encode that.

Answer (score 1):

[This email obfuscation library](https://github.com/Propaganistas/Email-Obfuscator) works really well for me, and I'm using a rich text field. Applies both to mailto links as well as unlinked email addresses.

You'll probably have to write a simple wrapper plugin to make it work as a twig extension. Also don't forget to include the library's JS file in the page's head so that it's loaded before it's needed.